# change position of Subsubsections and paragraphs and enumerate them

Tags: sectioning, numbering, sections-paragraphs

I am new to TeX. I have a document with subsubsections and paragraphs.

I don't wand the paragraphs inside the block, they should be bevor the block, like the subsubsection header bevor.

The other problem is, that subsubsections and paragraphs don't get enumerated and furthermore they're not listed inside ToC. Is there a possibility to solve this problem without doing it manually?

I use TeXmaker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To number subsubsections and paragraphs, set the `secnumdepth` counter to 4 (the paragraph level); to get them into the ToC, change the `tocdepth` counter also to 4; to change the formatting for the paragraph headings, you can use the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
  {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection}
\lipsum[2]
\paragraph{Test paragraph}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If, for some reason, using `titlesec` is not an option, you can redefine `\paragraph`; here's a little example of this approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
  {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1.5ex plus .2ex}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection}
\lipsum[2]
\paragraph{Test paragraph}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! Just a question: do you type this now to the answer or do you copy this example from somewhere?

Comment: @Sigur copy the example? I think I don't understand your question? In the first solution I used `titlesec`'s documentation to get the default settings for `\paragraph` and then changed them to produce the required formatting. In the second solution, I used the standard settings for `\paragraph` from `article.cls` and then made the necessary modifications.

Comment: Don't worry! I was asking if you type all the answer by hand or if you copy and paste the codes from some website or guide or pdf. I'm asking just for curiosity. I can not image how much time it takes you to type this. See you.